# firebase in iOS: keep get errors : -9806 and -13000 and -1200

Tags: swift, firebase, storage

i have an app with ios, it was work before, suddenly i stuck with firebase storage , and keep getting this error :

```
Error Domain=FIRStorageErrorDomain Code=-13000 "An unknown error occurred, please check the server response." UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, NSLocalizedDescription=An unknown error occurred, please check the server response., _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, NSErrorPeerCertificateChainKey=<CFArray 0x7fac75759f00 [0x10552ea40]>{type = immutable, count = 2, values = (
0 : <cert(0x7fac77956810) s: *.googleapis.com i: Google Internet Authority G3>
1 : <cert(0x7fac779562b0) s: Google Internet Authority G3 i: GlobalSign>
)}, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9806, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/abusultantawsel.appspot.com/o/9Jr1Cdgs9XXT5LSITXz7Kwj9esi2%2F556640855538.jpg?uploadType=resumable&name=9Jr1Cdgs9XXT5LSITXz7Kwj9esi2%2F556640855538.jpg, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fac75765470 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerTrust=<SecTrustRef: 0x7fac754362b0>, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9806, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9806, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerCertificates=<CFArray 0x7fac75759f00 [0x10552ea40]>{type = immutable, count = 2, values = (
0 : <cert(0x7fac77956810) s: *.googleapis.com i: Google Internet Authority G3>
1 : <cert(0x7fac779562b0) s: Google Internet Authority G3 i: GlobalSign>
)}}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/abusultantawsel.appspot.com/o/9Jr1Cdgs9XXT5LSITXz7Kwj9esi2%2F556640855538.jpg?uploadType=resumable&name=9Jr1Cdgs9XXT5LSITXz7Kwj9esi2%2F556640855538.jpg, NSErrorClientCertificateStateKey=0, object=9Jr1Cdgs9XXT5LSITXz7Kwj9esi2/556640855538.jpg, ResponseErrorDomain=NSURLErrorDomain, bucket=abusultantawsel.appspot.com, ResponseErrorCode=-1200, NSURLErrorFailingURLPeerTrustErrorKey=<SecTrustRef: 0x7fac754362b0>
```

my code is :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
 ////
    if Auth.auth().currentUser == nil {
        Auth.auth().signInAnonymously(completion: { (authResult, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print (error.localizedDescription)
                 } else {
                print ("you are login in")
            }
        })
    }
}

@IBAction func uploadimage(_ sender: Any) {
let profilePhoto : UIImage = myProfileImg.image!

if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(profilePhoto, 0.9) {

    let imagePath = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid +
    "/\(Int(Date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate * 1000)).jpg"

    let storageRef = self.storage.reference(withPath: imagePath)
    storageRef.putData(imageData, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
        if let error = error {

            print("Error uploading: \(error)")
            return
        }else{
            storageRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
                guard let downloadURL = url else {
                    // Uh-oh, an error occurred!

                    return
                }
                    let downloadString = downloadURL.absoluteString

            }

        }
    }
```

}

I tried to do a lot of thing but no benefit ,
 i set these setting in info.plist file :

```
<dict><key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
<dict>
    <key>appspot.com</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSRequiresCertificateTransparency</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
    <key>MY_PROJECT_NAME.appspot.com</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSRequiresCertificateTransparency</key>
        <false/>
        <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>firebaseio.com</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSRequiresCertificateTransparency</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
    <key>MY_PROJECT_NAME.firebaseio.com</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSRequiresCertificateTransparency</key>
        <false/>
        <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>firebasestorage.googleapis.com</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSRequiresCertificateTransparency</key>
        <false/>
        <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>googleapis.com</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSRequiresCertificateTransparency</key>
        <false/>
        <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>app-measurement.com</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSRequiresCertificateTransparency</key>
        <false/>
        <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
        <false/>
        <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</dict>
<key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
<true/>
<key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsForMedia</key>
<true/>
<key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
<true/><key>NSAllowsLocalNetworking</key>
<true/></dict>
```

I have also tried to create new project in (xcode) and new project with (firebase) , but still get this error.

also test on real device and simulator , nothing fix the error !